# Service running in Android 6.0.1 and not in Android 10

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-sensors, android-version

I have the following service declared in the manifest:

```
    <application
        ...

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.android.test.TestService"
            android:process=":Remote"
            android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.android.test.TestService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

and this is the Service class

```
public class TestService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {


    public class BatteryReceiver_andFileChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //TODO
        }
        // constructor
        public BatteryReceiver_andFileChecker(){
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        //TODO
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WakelockTimeout")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Logging service started new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Acquire wake lock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WLTAG:MyWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        //Display notification
        this.notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, this.notIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, this.channelID).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).setContentTitle("Test").setContentText("Sensor is recording").setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT).setContentIntent(this.pendingIntent);
        startForeground(this.NOTIFICATION, builder.build());


        //BatteryCheck
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        mReceiver = new BatteryReceiver_andFileChecker();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        //cancel notification
        stopForeground(true);

        //Unregister battery receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        //release wakeLock
        wakeLock.release();

        //Stop Service
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
//        super.onBind(intent);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {        
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }


}
```

And this services is created and terminated on two different "onclick" functions from the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ...

public void onClickStart(View v) {

        // Start Service
        this.intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestService.class);
        this.intent.putExtra("foo",foo);
        startService(this.intent);
    }

    public void onClickStopAcquisition(View v) {

        // Stop Service
        stopService(this.intent);
    }
}
```

This code runs as expecten in Android 6.0.1 and does not work on Android 10...
When I debug de app, no errors are fired when pressed the Start and Stop buttons in both OS, nevertheless, android 6.0.1 fires the service and android 10 does not...

Any reason why?

Just to keep in mind when understanding my implementation, my intention is to make a service which keeps running and doing stuff even if the user is not active in the application. Since I implementen the SensorEventListener to record data from sensors, my intention is to record data while the user might be interacting with the phone or even doing nothing (after he presses the power button of the phone, the service keeps running acquiring data and performing actions)

Then, the service should be terminated either when the user clicks the stop button or either when the MainActivity is terminated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should read more about background services and broadcast in android API 26 or higher

From the official documentation available [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services)

> If an app registers to receive broadcasts, the app's receiver consumes resources every time the broadcast is sent. This can cause problems if too many apps register to receive broadcasts based on system events; a system event that triggers a broadcast can cause all of those apps to consume resources in rapid succession, impairing the user experience. To mitigate this problem, `Android 7.0 (API level 24)` placed limitations on broadcasts, as described in Background Optimization. `Android 8.0 (API level 26)` makes these limitations more stringent.
>
> Apps that target `Android 8.0` or **higher** can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An
>   implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app
>   specifically. For example, `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is an implicit
>   broadcast, since it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them
>   know that some package on the device was replaced. However,
>   `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is not an implicit broadcast, since it is
>   sent only to the app whose package was replaced, no matter how many
>   other apps have registered listeners for that broadcast. Apps can
>   continue to register for explicit broadcasts in their manifests. Apps
>   can use `Context.registerReceiver()` at runtime to register a receiver
>   for any broadcast, whether implicit or explicit.

Broadcasts that require a signature permission are exempted from this restriction, since these broadcasts are only sent to apps that are signed with the same certificate, not to all the apps on the device

you should work with **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)**

**Important Update**

to answer your question in comment : use `WorkManager` for deferrable background tasks.

This library is backward compatible

It use `JobScheduler`,`FirebaseJobDispatcher` or `AlarmManager`

No Need to depend on play service library.

Recommended by Google for deferrable background work.

Can use features like chaining, constraints etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will give a look to the JobScheduler class to understand better how to proceed. Just a couple of things: Do you know any reliable example of jobscheduler with SensorEventListener? Does JobScheduler have retrocompatibility with API19?

Comment: Thanks for your update in your answer! Indeed  you have been of great help!

Just one last question, do you think that WorkManager could be combined with SensorEventListener to continously acquire Acc for long acquisition periods? Lets say: button clicked, Acc starts acquiring. Acc is acquired continously for 10h until button clicked again and Acc stops being acquired.

Would this be achievable with WorkManager?

Comment: For what I have been reading, could it be that I need to implement a ForegroundService, and that the reason in was not executing was because I was lacking the "ForeGroundService" Permission? (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)